# How to upload private files to s3 using boto3 and serializer

Tags: django, file, amazon-s3, boto3, serialization

I am using S3Boto3Storage to manage private file uploads to s3. When I upload via model, the upload works as expected.

When I upload via serializer, I get this error:

```
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Here are what my files look like:

// storage_backend.py

```
class PrivateFileStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_PRIVATE_FILE_LOCATION
    default_acl = 'private'
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
```

// settings.py

```
 DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.storage_backend.PrivateFileStorage'
```

// models.py

```
class PrivateFileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateFileStorage())
```

// serializers.py

```
class PrivateFileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PrivateFileModel
        fields = ('url', 'file')
```

// views.py

```
 json_obj = json.dumps(<some_object>)
 file_name = "{}".format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
 file = default_storage.open(file_name, 'w')
 file.write(json_obj)

 serializer = self.get_serializer(data={'file':file})
 serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # throws error

 # # saving the file directly to the model works just fine
 # file_instance = PrivateFileModel(file=file)
 # file_instance.save()
```

How do I integrate boto3 storage with django rest serializer?